# Securely executing system commands as sudo from PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, security, sudo

Is it possible?

I have written a command line tool in PHP for creating new environments for our company. It creates system users, directories, databases, VHosts and restarts apache, amongst other things. These commands require `sudo` privileges. I thought it might be a nice idea to have a web-interface for it, to make it easier for other non-developers to use. The web app would be behind authentication.

When running from the command line I just run `sudo tool.php`, obviously I can't do this from a web app.

How could I do this securely? Giving the apache user sudo access seems silly, as this would means all sites hosted on the box (eg all our environments) would have sudo access. Is it possible to make this tool run under a different user? this user could have sudo privileges for only the commands I need?

How do things like plesk and cPanel do this?

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does `tool.php` do?  Are you able to edit the sudoers command list on the server that `tool.php` is hosted on?

Comment: creates system users, databases, vhosts, restarts apache, etc. Yeah I have full control of the server, I just want to write something that is safe.

Comment: While I've added an answer that should get you sorted, I'd also make sure that my `tool.php` functions atomically -- if there are 5 steps and step 3/5 fails, have operations that return the server to the original state.

Comment: Thanks - Sure, the tool logs and rolls back any unsuccessful actions.

Comment: Awesome, logging details to a remote location is a great idea.  While I'm going to leave my answer as is, keep in mind that configuration management software such as Ansible, Chef, or Puppet have web interfaces and choosing an existing solution may save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 5):

While this approach lends itself to generating bad feelings, if this is a necessary evil, I'd begin by making sure that the server is segmented from the network -- either accessible only by a few hosts in a LAN or listening only to hosts that have authenticated against a VPN (or SSH tunnel).  In short, try not to let this host be low-hanging fruit.

It is possible to have a user with limited sudo-access and I would recommend doing so.

To begin, create a `sudoers` user that can only run `tool.php` and can be switched to via your `www-data` user (or whatever your webserving user happens to be named).  This will limit the scope of the sudo actions that can be taken on the server (however, if your tool.php is exploitable, this does not help).

You can do this by editing sudoers to contain a line like:

`online_tool_user ALL=(www-data) NOPASSWD: /var/danger/tool.php`

This will allow "online_tool_user" to run the command `/var/danger/tool.php` without entering a password. If this user tries to run any other commands (iptables, adduser, et al), it will be denied.

To make exploiting this user less fun for an attacker, look into using restricted shells or "jails."

Finally, if you're just calling `exec` via PHP, throw the user into the call, e.g.: `exec("sudo -u online_tool_user -c 'php /var/danger/tool.php'")`.

Comment: Nice, thank you, this is all good information. The tool is purely for ease of use, the server is a dev server (not found on our internal network), and is used only by us internally, occasionally by clients to check out specific sites, but these are all behind `htpasswd` auth (I know this isn't particularly strong protection).

Comment: Although, thinking about it, not sure this will actually work. It's my fault trying to simplify the explanation. The tool is not just one script. It is a collection of classes and components, which would just be used in the web-app. So the web app doesn't just call the tool o the command line, it performs the actions itself.

Comment: I assume you mean that you're calling actions from PHP that require escalated privileges.  I'd have to see some of your code to offer specific suggestions.

Comment: Sure - I'll post some in the morning

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to separate the web interface from the execution layer, i.e. use the web interface as the UI and to schedule actions. Then run a second job with `root` privileges that polls the queue, validates and executes scheduled tasks and which reports exit status back.

A slight modification to that is where instead of having the poller run independently  your web application can run that poller on-demand with sudo.

Another, less secure, approach is to run a second apache instance for your secure app that runs as `root` instead of `apache`. Last time I checked (a long long time ago) that was the approach web control panels used.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about the polling method, like using a cron to pick up the commands. This would definitely work but I like the idea of immediate feedback. I'll also check out the other approach!

Comment: Creating and modifying virtual hosts requires an Apache reload/restart which is not something you want to see happening 30 times in 5 minutes on a shared production server... And a new virtual host often requires a DNS modification as well also taking time to propagate  so letting your users wait until your system emails a task completed message may be a good idea.

Comment: It's a dev server, so none of that should happen. It will probably only be run a couple of times a week, so no massive overhead :)

Answer (score 0):

What about using setuid so that the process can be run as root?

```
 chmod 4555 tool.php
 chown root tool.php
```

I think that should do it correctly.

Comment: This does not address the asker's security questions and suggests that he has to interpret web-based commands as root.

Comment: @tristan setuid is specifically designed for situations like his and it does not require you to execute the command as root. in fact, it's made so you don't run as root. however, setuid only works on shebang executables in a few *nix systems so it may or may not work for him

Comment: setuid will let you execute the command as root, but it doesn't really address his question.  It's like being asked how to make a cake and responding "baking powder can be used to make a dough more fluffy."  While a helpful tidbit, it doesn't stand on its own as an answer to the question.